# C# asp.net- Using Chart controls- Sorting x axis into months

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, charts, bar-chart

I have a sql table with the customer details and the date they checked-in.
I have using chart controls to auto plot the graph, but the x-axis has the actual specific date they checked-in e.g. '09/11/17'. I want it to show the month they checked-in.
To do this I have thought about creating another column in the customer table to show the month they checked-in, but that seems inefficient.

Is there better method to do this?

my code in chart-page:

```
    public void load()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBconnection"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Check-In, Count(ID) AS ID FROM Customer GROUP BY Check-In ", con);
            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            Chart1.DataSource = dtbl;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Check-In";
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "ID";

        }
```

I am also new to c# chart controls, so it would be very much appreciated if anyone can provide me resources from which I can learn more!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this in the SQL statement itself, it would be a little redundant to store both the full date and the month separately. Try changing your query to:

```
"SELECT MONTH(Check-In), Count(ID) AS ID FROM Customer GROUP BY MONTH(Check-In)"
```

Note that this assumes the dates are from the same year